# Embedded video showing a black screen in revealjs slide

Tags: r, r-markdown, reveal.js

I'm using R Markdown to create slides for a class and I have a slide like this:

```markdown
## Troubled Lands

<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/eIchwB6xJJI" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
```

When I knit the file, it just shows a black rectangle instead of the YouTube video.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that I had `self-contained: true` in my YAML header. When I changed that to `self-contained: false` the video showed correctly.

I'm guessing that R tries to get all of the external media when making a slideshow self-contained, and that process fails when trying to get the YouTube video.